# Saving belongs_to data when creating new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hostess, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'hostess_id'
  validates_presence_of :hostess
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :parties, foreign_key: :hostess_id
end
```

When creating a new `Party`, the view lets the user select an existing `Hostess`, or enter a new one. (This is done with jQuery autocomplete to look up existing records.) If an existing record is chosen, `params[:party][:hostess_id]` will have the correct value. Otherwise, `params[:party][:hostess_id]` is `0` and `params[:party][:hostess]` has the data to create a new `Hostess` (e.g., `params[:party][:hostess][:first_name]`, etc.)

In the `Parties` controller:

```
def create
  if params[:party][:hostess_id] == 0
    # create new hostess record
    if @hostess = Person.create!(params[:party][:hostess])
      params[:party][:hostess_id] = @hostess.id
    end
  end
  @party = Party.new(params[:party])
  if @party.save
    redirect_to @party, :notice => "Successfully created party."
  else
    @hostess = @party.build_hostess(params[:party][:hostess])
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

This is working fine when I pass in an existing `Hostess`, but it's not working when trying to create the new `Hostess` (fails to create the new `Hostess/Person` and thus fails on creating the new `Party`). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the models you provided, you can have this setup in a cleaner way using a few rails tools like `inverse_of`, `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, `attr_accessor`, and callbacks.

```
# Model
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hostess, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'hostess_id', inverse_of: :parties
  validates_presence_of :hostess

  # Use f.fields_for :hostess in your form
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hostess

  attr_accessor :hostess_id

  before_validation :set_selected_hostess

  private
  def set_selected_hostess
    if hostess_id && hostess_id != '0'
      self.hostess = Hostess.find(hostess_id)
    end
  end
end

# Controller
def create
  @party = Party.new(params[:party])

  if @party.save
    redirect_to @party, :notice => "Successfully created party."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

We're doing quite a few things here.

First of all, we're using `inverse_of` in the `belongs_to` association, which allows you to [validate presence of the parent model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model).

Second, we're using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) which allows you to pass `params[:party][:hostess]` into the party model and let it build the hostess for you.

Third, we're setting up an `attr_accessor` for `:hostess_id`, which cleans up controller logic quite a bit, allowing the model to decide what to do whether it receives `hostess` object or the `hostess_id` value.

Fourth, we're making sure to override `hostess` with an existing hostess in case we got a proper `hostess_id` value. We do this by assigning hostess in the [`before_validation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback.

I didn't actually check if this code works, but hopefully it reveals enough information to solve your problem and exposes more helpful tools lurking in rails.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a thorough answer. Only change was in `def set_selected_hostess`, which needed to use the Person model, e.g., `self.hostess = Person.find(hostess_id)`. I also had attr_accessible in the model, which I commented out. Don't really need that anyway (was added by the generator).

Comment: you rock!!! Thank you very much!!! But I have a problem in Rails 4. I have: One Person has many tickets. And in the ticket form I need to fill with person attributes. When I do @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params) I get Couldn't find Person with ID=1 for Ticket with ID=